# Geometric Interpretation of Intersection Multiplicities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm taking a course on Algebraic curves, and this is excerpted from a portion of the lecture notes.

> Theorem: Let $p$ be a point of $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{2}$. There is a unique way to associate with each couple $(P, Q)$ of non-zero homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb{C}\left[x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}\right]$ an invariant $\mathbf{I}(p, P, Q)$ in $\mathbb{N} \cup\{\infty\}$ that satisfies the following six axioms.

1. Symmetry: $\mathbf{I}(p, P, Q)=\mathbf{I}(p, Q, P)$
2. Detects intersection points: $\mathbf{I}(p, P, Q) \neq 0$ if and only if $P(p)=Q(p)=0$.
3. Detects common components: $\mathbf{I}(p, P, Q)=\infty$ if and only if $P$ and $Q$ have a common irreducible factor that vanishes at $p$.
4. Transversality: suppose that $P$ and $Q$ both have degree one and that $Q$ is not of the form $\lambda P$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^{*} .$ If $p$ is the unique point in $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{2}$ such that $P(p)=Q(p)=0,$ then $\mathbf{I}(p, P, Q)=1$
5. Additivity: if $R$ is another non-zero homogeneous polynomial in $\mathbb{C}\left[x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}\right],$ then $\mathbf{I}(p, P, Q R)=$ $\mathbf{I}(p, P, Q)+\mathbf{I}(p, P, R)$
6. Deformation: assume that $\operatorname{deg}(Q) \geq \operatorname{deg}(P),$ and let $R$ be a homogeneous polynomial in $\mathbb{C}\left[x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}\right]$ of degree $\operatorname{deg}(Q)-\operatorname{deg}(P)$ such that $Q+P R \neq 0 .$ Then $\mathbf{I}(p, P, Q)=\mathbf{I}(p, P, Q+P R)$
   Moreover, if $P$ and $Q$ are non-constant and have no repeated factors, and we denote by $C$ and $D$ their zero sets in $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{2},$ then $\mathbf{I}(p, P, Q)=\mathbf{I}(p, C, D)$

The question is about axiom 5. The geometric translation of this axiom reads,

> If $E$ is another projective plane curve over $\mathbb{C}$ that does not have a common component with $D,$ then $\mathbf{I}(p, C, D \cup E)=\mathbf{I}(p, C, D)+\mathbf{I}(p, C, E)$.

The question is, why do we require $E$ to have no common component with $D$? Under the convention $\infty + \infty = \infty$, isn't whether or not $E$ has a common component with $D$ irrelevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible for $D,E$ to have a common component without having a common component with $C$, and this makes the additivity condition behave quite poorly. In the silliest case where $D=E$, we would have $I(p,C,D\cup E)=I(p,C,D)=I(p,C,E)$ for any $p$, which would imply that $I(p,C,D)=0$ for any $p,C,D$ where the invariant is not $\infty$. So intersection multiplicity could only ever give $0$ or $\infty$ if we didn't enforce the "no common component" requirement you're asking about.